# Showing the camera image with Datalogic C# SDK for Visual Studio's

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with Datalogic's SDK for Visual Studio.

I'm trying to get the image out of VPM (Vision Program Manager). You have to be a bit familiar with Datalogic's 'Impact' to know where I am talking about. I'm using the function GetData(). The following condition must be made:

```
                  Device.GetImagePortValue(VisionPort.CreateFromPath("Inspection.Image In Task:Image"), 
             Afterward.IfSuccess<VisionImage>((ImageInspection) =>
```

But That's not the case. Here is the complete Program:

```
using VisionSDK;
using VisionSDK.Drawing;
using VisionSDK.Events;


namespace SDKCameraImage
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    VisionDevice Device = VisionDevice.Create();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Device.SetupConnection(VisionDeviceConnectionDetails.CreateForNetworkConnection("127.0.0.1",10001,2000));

        GetData();

        Device.EventListener.DidAcquiredAnImage += (_, __) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Image Acquired");
            GetData();
        };

        Device.DeviceConnection.DidConnectHandler += (object sender, VisionEventArgs e) =>
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Connection");
        };

        Device.DeviceConnection.DidDisconnectHandler += (object sender, VisionEventArgs e) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Connection");
        };

        Device.Connect();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
             Device.GetImagePortValue(VisionPort.CreateFromPath("Inspection.Image In Task:Image"), 
             Afterward.IfSuccess<VisionImage>((ImageInspection) =>
         {
             ImageViewer.Background = new ImageBrush(ImageInspection.AsImageSource());
         }));

    }


  }
}
```

I have a connection with the camera. And the camera is in online state.

Hopefuly it's enough info. Thanks in advance!

Dirk

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

The solution is to use an image made by a Datalogic camera. If you use any other image it won't show in your application.

I'm not sure yet why this is  but now I know how to get it working!